# Duplication of values, followed by merging into whole matrix on R?

Tags: r, excel

I have a lat-lon data set of demand points along with their frequency of occurrence. Based on the frequency, I need to duplicate these values and merge them all into one big matrix with two columns, i.e., long and lat. ( For more clarity)

I've uploaded the relevant csv data here on dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vwmrym2e9xdo6u/input1.csv?dl=0.

I tried this in R and MS Excel. But, this was to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

Metalxenophobe

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using `rep`. First, download your data:

```
url <- "https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vwmrym2e9xdo6u/input1.csv?dl=1"
download.file(url, destfile = fn <- file.path(tempdir(), sub("(.*)\\?.*", "\\1", basename(url)))) # d/l
```

then process it:

```
df <- read.csv(fn) # read file
dfnew <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$Repeat), -1] # duplicate rows, omit 1st col
write.csv(dfnew, "output1.csv") # write file
```

Comment: That's essentially what I have in [the `expandRows` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/expandRows.R) in [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun). So, in this case, it would be: `library(SOfun); expandRows(df, "Repeat")` +1 :-)